# Profile Page not Showing The Statuses name and content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, show

Im creating a facebook clone using rails but i am stuck with the profile page not showing the Statuses and the content. This is the Code file:

Apps/Controller/profiles_controller.rb

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
   def show
    @user = User.find_by_profile_name(params[:id])
    if @user
        @statuses = @user.statuses.all
        render action: :show
    else
    render file: 'public/404' , status: 404 , formats: [:html]
    end
  end
end
```

Apps/views/profiles/show.html.erb

```
<%if @statuses%>

    <% @statuses.each do |status| %>
    <%= status.content %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: my github account :  https://github.com/Ahmedalthani/Skillbook/commits/master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller action, to grab the `user`, you should do:

```
@user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

Also, you could use `find` method instead of `find_by_id`:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

in this case, it will throw an exception when `user` with `id` is not found in the database.

#### Update after working on your project from github:

So, you have a few problems. To fix those, do:

In your `config/routes.rb` file add:

```
resources :profiles
```

Change `apps/views/profiles/show.html.erb` to this:

```
<% if @statuses %>
      <% @statuses.each do |status| %>
             <div class="well"/>
              <%= status.content %>
       <%end%>
<%end%>
```

In `profiles_controller.rb` you already have the correct code:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
   def show
     @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])

     if @user
       @statuses = @user.statuses.all
       render action: :show
     else
       render file: 'public/404' , status: 404 , formats: [:html]
     end
  end
end
```

Make these changes and your profiles page `http://localhost:3000/profiles/1` will work like a charm :-) [I just tested on my computer].

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried that but now i am getting this error "The page you were looking for doesn't exist. You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved."

Comment: @AHmed I have cloned your repo locally and fixed all your problems. The profile page is working as expected now. I can't push to your github repo as I don't have access. But, I have updated my answer. Make those changes and it will work like a charm :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have edited the routes page along with profile show page but when i view the show page i still get a blank page and the loop that was created in the show page is not rendering.    Here how the profile page appears   http://postimg.org/image/dk76srekl/

Comment: You see the blank page when `@statuses` is blank means you have no status for that user in the database. If you create some status for a user, then you will see those status. I have checked on my computer. With my code, it work and shows the statuses for that user. Let me know if you have any other question. Also, if you want you can give me push access to your repo, then I will push the latest code and you will be able to pull it from ther.

Comment: ok can you please give me your Github username so i can add you as a collaborator ?

Comment: rakibulislam is my github

Comment: i added you as a collabarator. please check you github page :)